# TeamCity does not see provisioning profiles on MacOS

Tags: xamarin, teamcity

We have set up TeamCity instance on MacOS. Everything works as expected. Only problem we have it TeamCity does not see provisioning profiles:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(606,3): error : The specified iOS provisioning profile 'Test.Development' could not be found [/Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/b35069a0a4b41b2a/iOS/Skellig.iOS.csproj]

This is Xamarin application and we have successfully downloaded all certificates and provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that one of the certificates or provisioning profiles are missing a private key? Or is the TeamCity instance installed on the same MacOS that the original certificates and provisioning profiles were created on?

Comment: No, because I can build app with VisualStudio for MAC or MSBuild from command prompt. It is related to permissions and wrong path, but I can not figure out what is the problem